# Deleting and restoring items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to delete and restore items in this fashion:
when deleted (by pressing the red 'x') a picture of the item will appear in the navbar,
when the image is clicked in the navbar, the item will be restored onto the page.

---

As you can see, the last two functions that are currently commented out are what I have been trying to use to implement this functionality, however when I remove the comment '/*' my other javascript functions stop working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-cookie-master"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/carousel.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shopping.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"                                                      href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery- ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <h4><mark>Student Project #5 H.B.</mark></h4></br>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand deleted-item hidden"  id="box1">
            <img  class="navpics" src="surface3.jpg" alt="Microsoft Surface">
            </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand deleted-item hidden" id="box2">
            <img class="navpics" src="surface3cover.jpg" alt="Microsoft Surface Type Cover">
            </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand deleted-item hidden" id="box3">
            <img class="navpics" src="mabook.jpg" alt="Apple Macbook Pro Retina">
            </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand deleted-item hidden" id="box4">
            <img class="navpics" src="superdrive.jpg" alt="Apple SurperDrive">
            </a>
        <a class="navbar-brand deleted-item hidden" id="box5">
            <img class="navpics" src="case1.jpg" alt="Laptop Case">
            </a>    
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h2>Premium Computer Supplies!</h2>
</header>
    <ul id="sortable" style="list-style-type:none">
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
<!--<div id="all">-->    
    <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="row" id="box1">
        <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img  class="bodypics" id="a" src="surface3.jpg" alt="Microsoft Surface">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <h3>Microsoft Surface Pro 3</h3>
                <div class="description" id="pnd1" hidden>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div >
                <p>With a variety of processors and memory options, there's a Surface for everyone!</p>
                    <p>Starting at $999!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="row" id="box2">
        <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img class="bodypics" id="b" src="surface3cover.jpg" alt="Microsoft Surface Type Cover">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <h3>Microsoft Surface Pro 3 Typer Cover</h3>
                <div class="description" id="pnd2" hidden>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>The Type Cover is a perfect accessory for your Surface!</p>
                    <p>Starting at $129!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="row" id="box3">
        <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img class="bodypics" id="c" src="mabook.jpg" alt="Apple Macbook Pro Retina">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <h3>Macbook Pro Retina Display</h3>
                <div class="description" id="pnd3" hidden>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>The Macbook is a must-have for students, parents, and more!</p>
                    <p>Starting at $1299!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="row" id="box4">
        <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img class="bodypics" id="d" src="superdrive.jpg" alt="Apple SurperDrive">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <h3>Apple SuperDrive</h3>
                <div class="description" id="pnd4" hidden>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Able to read disks, the SuperDrive is essential for burning music and home-movies!</p>
                    <p>Starting at $79!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
    <li class="ui-state-default"><div class="row" id="box5">
        <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
        <!--<div class="col-sm-3">-->
            <!--Insert picture-->
            <img class="bodypics" id="e" src="case1.jpg" alt="Laptop Case">
            <!--Accordion heading-->
            <h3>Laptop Case</h3>
                <div class="description" id="pnd5" hidden>
                <!--Description and price-->
                <div>
                <p>Carry your computer with you anywhere with a computer bag!</p>
                    <p>Starting at $39!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
<!----------------------------------------------------------------->
<script>

    $( ".row" ).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ 
            fontSize : '17', 
            opacity : '0.6',
        }, 1);
    });

    $( ".row" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ 
            fontSize : '14',
            opacity : '1',
        }, 1);
    });

  $("div#box1").click(function(){
        $("#pnd1").animate({
            hidden: 'toggle'
        });
    });

    $("div#box2").click(function(){
        $("#pnd2").animate({
            hidden: 'toggle'
        });
    });

    $("div#box3").click(function(){
        $("#pnd3").animate({
            hidden: 'toggle'
        });
    });

    $("div#box4").click(function(){
        $("#pnd4").animate({
            hidden: 'toggle'
        });
    });

    $("div#box5").click(function(){
        $("#pnd5").animate({
            hidden: 'toggle'
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

  });

    $('button.close').click(function() {
       $(this).parent().animate({
           'opacity': 0
       }, 1, function() {
           $(this).css({'display': 'none'})
                })

        $(".deletedItem#" + name).toggleClass("hidden");
        }); 

    $(".deleted-item").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".row#" + name).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.bodypics {
    width:290px;
    height:200px;
}
header{
    background-color: royalblue;
    color:gold;
    padding-left: 0;
    width:100%
}
body{
    width:90%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-size: 3;
    padding-left: 5%
}
.row{
    background-color: white;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    border: 1px solid royalblue;
    margin: 2px;
}
#all{
    width:90%;
}
#sortable li {
    height: 402px;
    float: left;
}
.close{
    color:red;
}
.navpics{
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Also here is a jsfiddle. Thank You all again in advance. http://jsfiddle.net/hbteibet/4tqqrLa7/2/

Comment: The reason the rest of the Javascript stops working when you uncomment those lines is that they cause errors. In fact, there is a rather obvious mistake in that they are missing some `;` at the end of the lines.

Comment: I thought because the js/jquery is in my html file and not an external file that semicolons weren't necessary

Comment: No, they are always needed. You also have a typo, `funtion` should be `function`.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the semicolons and fixing that typo are now allowing my js to function, however the images are not appearing in the navbar when deleted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out! Mainly a combination of me being careless and inexperienced, but here's the solution:
 Just change this last bit of code:

```
 $('button.close').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).parent().attr("id");
       $(this).parent().toggleClass("hidden");
        $(".deleted-item#" + name).toggleClass("hidden");
        }); 

    $(".deleted-item").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
        var name = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".row#" + name).toggleClass("hidden");
    });
```

And now all is dandy!